# In Corona SDK, why is object.X nil when a value is assigned?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I did some research prior to posting this question. But, I couldn't find a clear answer so I decided to post it. Basically, I'm trying to get a rectangular object move across the screen by changing the x position. But, I can't perform the function because I am receiving an error saying that "brick01.X is nil." Any ideas?

```
local brick01 = display.newRect(_W/2,math.random(1,8)*32,50,32)
--brick01.anchorX = 0
--brick01.anchorY = 0
brick01:setFillColor(0,0,0)

print(brick01.X) -- Returns Nil 


local function update(event)
   updateBackgrounds()
end

function updateBackgrounds()
   --far background movement
   brick01.X = brick01.X - (4)
end 


timer.performWithDelay(1,update,-1)
```

Comment: `obj.x` is NOT `obj.X`, where did you give `brick01.X ` the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use brick01.x not brick01.X.